# Replacing NAs With Zeros - Error in bmerge

Tags: r

```
SubjectsYOY[c("MultiOrderFlag")][is.na(SubjectsYOY[c("MultiOrderFlag")])]<-0
```

I cannot figure what I am doing incorrectly with the basic code above.

It works earlier in my code, but not later.

The error message follows:

```
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  typeof x.subjectkey (integer) != typeof i.V1 (character)
```

Comment: what do you get by `SubjectsYOY[c("MultiOrderFlag")]`?

Comment: Based on the error message it's clear you're working with a `data.table` -- the way to achieve this with proper `data.table` syntax is `SubjectsYOY[is.na(MultiOrderFlag), MultiOrderFlag := 0]`

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `data.frame`, using `[` is still a `data.frame`  with one column unless the `,` is used.

```
subjectsYOY[, "MultiOrderFlag"][is.na(SubjectsYOY[, "MultiOrderFlag"])] <-0
```

Or with `[[`

```
subjectsYOY[["MultiOrderFlag"]][is.na(SubjectsYOY[[ "MultiOrderFlag"]])] <-0
```

Comment: Thank you again - Now I wish to conditionally replace it based on another variable then what would I do? Perhaps something like the following?subjectsYOY[, "MultiOrderFlag"][is.na(SubjectsYOY & !is.na(SubjectsYOY["sk2017"],[, "MultiOrderFlag"])] <-0

Comment: @Zach  Instead of the `is.n` on the 'MultOrderFlag', change it to another variable name